# overwrite a single line with fortran

Tags: fortran, overwrite

I am wondering how to edit a single line in an existing file without overwriting the rest of that file with fortran? I tried

access = 'append'
or
status = 'replace'
or 
status = 'default'

but all of them gives me a a file which is changed on that specific line but the rest of the file is empty.

Thanks!

Comment: If it's a single line you want to change, why not use `Ctrl+F` inside a text editor to find the string you are looking for, and then change it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean an existing sequential file, I don't think that you could do this in Fortran.  Perhaps if the lines were of fixed length and you opened it as a direct access file, you could modify a line in the middle without changing lines before or after.  If the lines are of variable length (indicated by the Fortran EOL for that OS), then I don't think you can modify an existing file.   The easiest solution is probably to copy the file to a new file, copying most lines and modifying the one.

Comment: I could think of a direct access file of `character(1)`, but must be careful to achieve the right result.